# Microsoft Graph API 401 when accessing calendar events

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm currently trying to create a basic website to run locally on a raspberry pi that shows me my outlook calendar for the day. However, when I try and access the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events` endpoint, I get a 401 unauthorized error.

This is for a simple node.js express server, with all of the code for interacting with the graph api coming from the [javascript quickstart app](https://github.com/azure-samples/ms-identity-javascript-graphapi) provided by Microsoft. The quickstart app works fine, and I'm able to see the json response for the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` endpoint that is part of the demo, but changing the endpoint causes a 401.

I've made sure in the azure app registration page that I've enabled the `Calendar.read` permission, and in my app I've added the `calendar.read` permission to my scope. When I login, the login popup window asks for permission to read my calendar which to me says that the app should have access to my calendar.

My application configuration (again based off of the quickstart app) looks like this:

```
const applicationConfig = {
    clientID: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    graphScopes: ['calendars.read', 'tasks.read'],
    graphEndpoint: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events',
};
```

Other than these changes, the rest of the code is identical to the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You should also include `User.Read` in your scopes. From the [documentation on User.Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference?toc=./ref/toc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0#user-permissions):

> Allows users to sign-in to the app, and allows the app to read the profile of signed-in users. It also allows the app to read basic company information of signed-in users.

```
const applicationConfig = {
    clientID: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    graphScopes: ['Users.Read', 'Calendars.Read', 'Tasks.Read'],
    graphEndpoint: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events',
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I took it out because I didn't think that I needed it, unfortunately I'm still getting 401's

Comment: Interesting. Which line is tossing the 401?

Comment: What always helps me greatly is copying the access token and pasting in into https://jwt.ms this will explain all the claims of the token and that might give you a hint about the mistake.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I'm not sure what you mean by which line, I get the 401 trying to access the endpoint defined at `graphEndpoint`